# combinelasted httpclient and translate in angular 6

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

```
    Observable.combineLatest([
        this.httpClient.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/v1/items'),
        this.translateService.onLangChange.asObservable()
    ])
```

In Angular 6, When I subscribe Observable above, it does not return results immediately.

Comment: Try to explain problems briefly and define all the variables and functions properly

Answer (score 0):

With the little information you gave, there are two things which may defer it:

1. your first observable is asynchronous, so it will always take some time
2. `combineLatest` requires all observables to **emit at least once** before the resulting observable emits the combined result. Are you sure both observables have emitted at least once?